# Using Height and Area for plotting histogram of each marker in FACS

Tags: flow-cytometry

I had a flow cytometry experiment. After normal filter with cell debris and doublet cells, I would like to gate the cells by different markers. However, I get confused to use which parameter to plot out the histogram/ scattered dot plot. More specifically, for each fluorescent channel, there are 3 options: height, width, and area. I know that width is only related to the cell size while height and area both correlate with the signal intensity. I would like to know which measurement (i.e. height or area) should I use to plot the graph?

Someone suggested that if I am analyzing different cell populations with different shapes/sizes, I should use the height. I wonder whether this is true.

Thanks!

Comment: Height is most typically used for fluorescent channels, but not necessarily for forward and side scatter. For example, you'll look at a plot and see FL2-H vs FL1-H. Experiment by substituting the different options and see how your plots change, if at all.